# string in list of list

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have two lists like:

`DevInDB = ['Dev1','Dev2','Dev3']`
and
`DevInMesh  = [['Dev1',0,0],['Dev2',1,1]]`

I want to know if, for any DevInDB string, there is the same string in DevInMesh.

I wrote this code that works (in python)

```
for dev in DevInDB:
    if any(dev in DevMesh for DevMesh in DevInMesh  ):
        print(dev)
    else:
        print('no')
```

I try to ust this code in a HTML file using jinja, but the 'any' function doesn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compute this before sending it to `jinja`.

**Ex:**

```
DevInDB = ['Dev1','Dev2','Dev3']  
DevInMesh  = [['Dev1',0,0],['Dev2',1,1]]

DevInMesh = {k for k, *_ in DevInMesh}
DevInDB = [(i, i in DevInMesh) for i in DevInDB]
print(DevInDB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way:

```
  {% for DevDB in DevInDB %}
  {% set ns = namespace(foo=false) %} 

    {% for DevMesh in DevInMesh  %}
      {% if DevMesh [0] == DevDB %}
        {% set ns.foo = True %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

and later on:

```
{% if ns.foo %}
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `any` expression with the simple list comprehension where non-empty list will be True:

```py
[1 for DevMesh in DevInMesh if dev in DevMesh]
```

Or better is to remove the computational part from template because a template is the view part that works on presentation level of the context, such that all pre-computed expressions should be stored in the context and only printed in the template.